# How to add bar level labels with cli-chart in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am building a command line chart in Node.js.
Here's the code:

```
var Chart = require('cli-chart');
var chart = new Chart({
    xlabel: 'X axis label',
    ylabel: 'Y axis label',
    direction: 'x',
    width: 20,
    height: 10,
    lmargin: 15,
    step: 2
});

chart.addBar(3, 'red');
chart.addBar(5, 'blue');
chart.addBar(7, 'yellow');
chart.addBar(10, 'green');
chart.draw();
```

Now the labels that I have defined above are for the y-axis and x-axis.
I would, however, like to define a label for each bar, maybe on top of the bar or just next to it.
Is this possible with cli-chart and if not, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seems to have a builtin option to add bar label in *[cli-chart](https://github.com/andrewjstone/cli-chart)* library, but you could use `charm.write()` method to do it in a hacky way, modifying the *cli-chart* `drawBars` prototype.

```
var Chart = require('cli-chart');

Chart.prototype.drawBars = function() {  // overrinding the cli-chart drawBars prototype
  // set scale based on max_size
  if (this.direction === 'x') {
    this.scale = this.width/this.max_size;
  } else {
    this.scale = this.height/this.max_size;
  }

  var charm = this.charm;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.bars.length; i++) {
    if (this.direction === 'x') {
      charm.up(3).write(chart.barLabels[i]).pop();  // added line to write bar label
      if (i != 0) charm.up(this.step);
      else charm.up(1).write(chart.barLabels[i]).pop();  // added line to write first bar label
    } else {
      if (i != 0) charm.right(this.step);
    }
    charm.push();
    this.bars[i].draw(this.scale);
    charm.pop();
  }
  if (this.direction === 'x') charm.down(this.step*this.bars.length+1);
  charm.write('\n\n\n');
  if (this.direction === 'y') charm.write('\n');
};


var chart = new Chart({
    xlabel: 'X axis label',
    ylabel: 'Y axis label',
    direction: 'x',
    width: 20,
    height: 10,
    lmargin: 15,
    step: 2
});

chart.barLabels = [  // add bar labels to chart
  'bar label one', 'bar label two', 'bar label three', 'bar label four'
]

chart.addBar(3, 'red');
chart.addBar(5, 'blue');
chart.addBar(7, 'yellow');
chart.addBar(10, 'green');
chart.draw();
```

However, it would be more clean to add an option to the `Chart` constructor directly in the library.

[image]